# How do I fix KeyError while parsing instagram?

Tags: python, python-3.x, parsing, instagram

Everyone,

I have a small script parsing names on Instagram.
Recently started having this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/jpegcoma/vk/posting_instagram.py", line 361, in <module>
    main()
  File "/home/jpegcoma/vk/posting_instagram.py", line 293, in main
    table_of_content = get_stuf_from_url(urls)
  File "/home/jpegcoma/vk/posting_instagram.py", line 64, in get_stuf_from_url
    if json.loads(shared_data)["entry_data"]["ProfilePage"][0]["graphql"]["user"]["is_private"] == False:
KeyError: 'ProfilePage'
```

Currently it is running on some server. However, I tryed it on my laptop and script was working.

Here is the code that does the thing:

```
import requests
import json
import os
import random
from time import sleep
import time
import re
from io import BytesIO
from PIL import Image
from multiprocessing import Pool
from multiprocessing.dummy import Pool as ThreadPool

file_name = 'users_names.txt'

def create_folder_photos():    
   if os.path.isdir(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), "photos")) == False:
       os.makedirs(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), "photos"))
   else:
       pass

def make_list_of_users_to_scrap(file_name):
   '''Opens file with instagram user_names.
      Every name should be on a new line.
      Prepares full URL for parsing.
      Returns list URLs'''

   path = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), file_name)
   base_url = 'https://www.instagram.com/'
   users_url_dic = []
   with open(path, 'r') as file:
       for name in file:
           users_url_dic.append(base_url + name.rstrip() + '/')
   return users_url_dic

def parsed_data(shared_data):
   '''Get to ["edges"] node in shared_data from instagram'''
   return json.loads(shared_data)['entry_data']['ProfilePage'][0]['graphql']['user']['edge_owner_to_timeline_media']["edges"]

def get_stuf_from_url(urls):    
   # Open a request session
   with requests.session() as s:
       # Add some headers in case
       s.headers['user-agent'] = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/67.0.3396.87 Safari/537.36'

       pool = ThreadPool(5)
       d={}
       # Go throught all the URLs on instagram
       responce = pool.map(requests.get, urls)
       pool.close()
       pool.join()
       for i in responce:
           c = i.text

           if 30000 < len(c) < 180000:
               # Clean html, take only content of 'sharedData' part
               shared_data = c.split('window._sharedData = ')[1].split(';</script>')[0]
               # Check is accaunt is private
               if json.loads(shared_data)["entry_data"]["ProfilePage"][0]["graphql"]["user"]["is_private"] == False:
                   # Go throught all the nodes:
                   # If video - pass.
                   # If photo - take {"Id":"URL"}
                   for node in parsed_data(shared_data)[::]:
                       if node['node']['is_video'] == False:                            
                           d[node['node']['id']] = node['node']['display_url']
                       else:
                           continue
               else:
                   continue
           else:
               continue
   return d


def check_for_new(new_data_from_request):
   '''Open 'before_log.txt with previous loggs {'id':'url'}
      Check if any new data is presented.
      Write 2 new files:
      "added.txt" - new photos with url from the last time
      "before_log.txt" - updated log with all the ids and urls
      returns dic with added {'id':'url'} photos'''

   # Open a before_log.txt or say that no such file is presented.
   if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'before_log.txt')):
       with open(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'before_log.txt'), mode='r', encoding='utf8') as f_file:
           before_log = json.load(f_file)
   else:
       print('Need to make "before_log.txt" file to use the script!!!')

   # Get new data from "def get_stuf_from_url(urls):"            
   after = new_data_from_request

   # Check if any new photos is avaliable
   added = {i:after[i] for i in after if not i in before_log}  

   # Add new {key:value} to before_log
   for key, value in after.items():
       if key not in before_log.keys():
           before_log[key] = value

   # Write added and before_log for future use    
   with open(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'added.txt'), mode='w', encoding='utf8') as add_file:
       add_file.write(json.dumps(added) + '\n')
   with open(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'before_log.txt'), mode='w', encoding='utf8') as out_file:
       out_file.write(json.dumps(before_log) + '\n')

   print('We got {} new photos.'.format(len(added)))          
   return added

def createFilename(url, name, folder):
   result = re.split(r'.jpg', url)
   slashSplit = result[0].split('/')
   if name == None:
       name = slashSplit[-1]
   ext = "jpg"
   file = '{}{}.{}'.format(folder, name, ext)
   return file

def getImageFast(url, name=None, folder= os.path.join(os.getcwd(), "photos/")):
   '''Download new photos from instagram
      Creates a photos folder'''
   print("Downloading photos.....")
   file = createFilename(url, name, folder)
   r = requests.get(url, stream=True)
   i = Image.open(BytesIO(r.content))
   i.save(file)
```

I guess the problem is somewhere in here

```
if json.loads(shared_data)["entry_data"]["ProfilePage"][0]["graphql"]["user"]["is_private"] == False:
```

Some examples of parsed names on instagram:

```
_nail_ann_
alena.nails.tallinn
alyne_nails
anna_nails_erbil
aquarelle_nailstudio
cantinhodalara_nails
```

In a shorter version it does work as intended:

```
urls = 'https://www.instagram.com/_linails_/'
responce = requests.get(urls)
response_text= responce.text
shared_data = response_text.split('window._sharedData = ')[1].split(';</script>')[0]
#     print(shared_data)
d={}
f = json.loads(shared_data)['entry_data']['ProfilePage'][0]['graphql']['user']['edge_owner_to_timeline_media']["edges"]
for node in f[::]:
    if node['node']['is_video'] == False:
        d[node['node']['id']] = node['node']['display_url']
    else:
        continue
print (d)
```

After running it I'm getting all the URL and ids I need:

```
{
'2073876006313498489': 'https://scontent-lax3-2.cdninstagram.com/vp/6e5c8c22e54aa0c853ee88db05dc79bf/5E1BBCA4/t51.2885-15/e35/65217639_634723610367271_4450988163128206846_n.jpg?_nc_ht=scontent-lax3-2.cdninstagram.com&_nc_cat=107',
'2024498169693824735': 'https://scontent-lax3-2.cdninstagram.com/vp/39188272c2305ed250ad466c7a715b91/5E2F4B15/t51.2885-15/e35/56352792_132736304460754_8293153588685230511_n.jpg?_nc_ht=scontent-lax3-2.cdninstagram.com&_nc_cat=110',
'2023266828574689831': 'https://scontent-lax3-2.cdninstagram.com/vp/f313d44c5bd398a8e6b3f04fb7dbb739/5E2BBB71/t51.2885-15/e35/56578225_1055286461334820_1507399846418163801_n.jpg?_nc_ht=scontent-lax3-2.cdninstagram.com&_nc_cat=104',
'2016110942668250132': 'https://scontent-lax3-2.cdninstagram.com/vp/349bbf6a920e440a4e71d5b2d149a61b/5E2BB7FE/t51.2885-15/e35/53745148_280247652888437_7055433742029015170_n.jpg?_nc_ht=scontent-lax3-2.cdninstagram.com&_nc_cat=105',
'2012783478764415885': 'https://scontent-lax3-2.cdninstagram.com/vp/72dfe2f67b6dc1ea75e2ddd832384475/5E1936CE/t51.2885-15/e35/54512001_2155869857812437_3429908829670998264_n.jpg?_nc_ht=scontent-lax3-2.cdninstagram.com&_nc_cat=109',
'2012464856204377926': 'https://scontent-lax3-2.cdninstagram.com/vp/5aefc3a4e047b08dc94366b0723f170d/5E32A5D3/t51.2885-15/e35/54513720_424627718315641_3423874379564248817_n.jpg?_nc_ht=scontent-lax3-2.cdninstagram.com&_nc_cat=101',
'2008135031155279090': 'https://scontent-lax3-2.cdninstagram.com/vp/09cc2e7631c115a0131bda6f597dde60/5E1B4C09/t51.2885-15/e35/53156526_1025783867629475_1693464480553968728_n.jpg?_nc_ht=scontent-lax3-2.cdninstagram.com&_nc_cat=111',
'2004990756607236359': 'https://scontent-lax3-2.cdninstagram.com/vp/5da04c640d70b52a3e3073667985f8e3/5E2A62EB/t51.2885-15/e35/54266355_225989821600275_560245954300705815_n.jpg?_nc_ht=scontent-lax3-2.cdninstagram.com&_nc_cat=103',
'2002388991416431681': 'https://scontent-lax3-2.cdninstagram.com/vp/77bb0bf9878ca2d175dbd51350c1ef03/5E37974D/t51.2885-15/e35/53217305_581829868953428_1147405223061346025_n.jpg?_nc_ht=scontent-lax3-2.cdninstagram.com&_nc_cat=108',
'2001312091952564411': 'https://scontent-lax3-2.cdninstagram.com/vp/64326e9675b389a7997ed86980cba7bc/5E30992A/t51.2885-15/e35/54513758_391705221628749_737855016941810571_n.jpg?_nc_ht=scontent-lax3-2.cdninstagram.com&_nc_cat=109',
'1999425996532762294': 'https://scontent-lax3-2.cdninstagram.com/vp/4c4a5ee2b0ad46d6e3eeb1a30c1e9130/5E1BC2CA/t51.2885-15/e35/52639028_2494445767266095_4453054116414455580_n.jpg?_nc_ht=scontent-lax3-2.cdninstagram.com&_nc_cat=111',
'1993652807341169347': 'https://scontent-lax3-2.cdninstagram.com/vp/d6d8ffef7fd23d1f12b14282d3bc9aca/5E17386F/t51.2885-15/e35/52024250_786523341734970_6491735451376989098_n.jpg?_nc_ht=scontent-lax3-2.cdninstagram.com&_nc_cat=106'
}
```

Comment: Check the content of `json.loads(shared_data)["entry_data"]` or even `json.loads(shared_data)`. Probably there is some kind of error and no `ProfilePage` key

Comment: I did. I think it might be some individual answeres for particular user response data. I thought my design would eliminate this problem if it is something apart from what we intended to receive, but looks like not